# Summing values by character in SAS

Tags: sas

I created this fakedata as an example:

```
data fakedata;
length name $5;
infile datalines;
input name count percent;
return;
datalines;
Ania 1 17
Basia 1 3
Ola 1 10
Basia 1 52
Basia 1 2
Basia 1 16
;
run;
```

The result I want to have is:

[image: table]

---> summed counts and percents for Basia

I would like to have summed count and percent for Basia as she was only once in the table with count 4 and percent 83. I tried exchanging name into a number to do GROUP BY in proc sql but it changes into order by (I had such an error). Suppose that it isn't so difficult, but I can't find the solution. I also tried some arrays without any success. Any help appreciated!

Comment: You should include the output that you want to get.

Comment: Okay, im writting

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like `proc sql` does what you want:

```
proc sql;
    select name, count(*) as cnt, sum(percent) as sum_percent
    from fakedata
    group by name;
```

You can add a `where` clause to get the results just for one name.

Comment: it occured an error: Summary functions are restricted to the SELECT and HAVING clauses only :(

Comment: @aniusni . . . The `order by` doesn't seem necessary for your result.  Anyway, you can use `order by `sum_percent` if you want things in order.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, actually I got an answer.

```
proc summary data=fakedata;
by name;
var count percent;
output out=wynik (drop = _FREQ_ _TYPE_) sum(count)=count sum(percent)=percent;
run;
```

Comment: Your syntax is a bit redundant you could have used.
output out=wynik (drop=_:) sum=;

Answer (score 0):

You can go back a step and use PROC FREQ most likely to generate this output in a single step. Based on counts the percents are not correct, but I'm not sure they're intended to be, right now they add up to over 100%. If you already have some summaries, then use the `WEIGHT` statement to account for the counts.

```
proc freq data=fakedata;
table name;
weight count;
run;
```